# iOS - denied code sign permissions, now can't build

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, code-signing, xcode9.2

I downloaded an SDK (for Mavick drones) and built the sample app for the simulator - everything was fine! However, when I built to run on my iPhone, it spawned a number of keychain request windows for giving permissions to code signing. There seemed to be hundreds, so I clicked 'deny' on one, and everything stopped.

Now however, every time I try to build the app for my iPhone, code signing fails with `unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff`. I've tried restarting Xcode, cleaning the project etc, but nothing seems to fix this.

What can I do to get code signing working again?

Comment: To run app in real device you must have provisional certificate.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I already have profiles and certificates correctly set up

Comment: Add your image screen shot of you app general.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting my Mac, instead of just Xcode, fixed the issue. Hopefully someone finds this useful!

Comment: thank you you save my life. i almost cried when all my project cant be open haha thanks dude